# When using random numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers

After I imported the math class...

Math.random()

I am confused at how to make the range of the numbers. I know you can multiply, and then add/subtract, but the logic is not making sense to me, and I am also not overly sure how to make the range. Can I get some help?

Comment: Can you describe your situation and confusion in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the range [min, max], then you can use this formula:

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min
```

Comment: +1: You don't need to know which max or min. `Math.random() * (a - b) + b` will also work regardless of `a > b` or `b > a` ;)

Comment: @Peter: I got lucky on that one!

Answer (score 1):

```
random()
```

Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Make your own arrangement like if you need it below 50 multiply it by 50.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a range of integers from 0 to n, then look at [java.util.Random nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Comment: Given that they have problems with `Math.random()` already, I guess there is a *lot* of explanation necessary for them to use `java.util.Random` correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() returns a double in between 0 and 1. So, say you wanted a number between 0 and 10:

```
double random = Math.random()*10;
```

Or maybe a range from -10 to 10:

```
double random = (Math.random()-0.5)*20;
```

Notice how I did *20 instead of 10. Subtracting 0.5 would then return a value between -0.5 and 0.5, so 0.5*20 = 10 and -0.5*20 = -10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe you problem more. Anyway, in Java, there is class which is created specifically for working with Random numbers. Which is `java.util.Random`. Refer [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for more details. It has many methods which helps you to work with random numbers in many ways.

Some of the methods are `nextInt(int limit)` will give a random value between zero(inclusive) and limit(exclusive). If you need real numbers, then you have `nextDouble()` which will give a value between 0.0 and 1.0.